# jQuery Liquid slider not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, slider, compatibility

I am having trouble getting the Liquid Slider to work in IE.

It works fine in Safari, Chrom and Firefox but fails in all versions of Internet Explorer including 9.  In IE 9 it only shows navigation and no content, in IE 8 it shows the first panel but no navigation and in IE 7 it shows all panels stacked.

The website can be found at http://michaelcranis.com/portfolio

Any help would be greatly appreciated!